# Post increment within a loop

Tags: java

I would really appreciate it if someone could properly explain why j++ does not increase in value (++j works though). After I run the program, it outputs 0 instead of 100.

```
public static void calculate() {
    int j = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        j=j++;
    }

    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read it well. You'll find out that it does!

Comment: It does, actually. The assignment is the last operation to take place, and what is assigned is the old value of `j`, which will always be 0. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @Aominè You are wrong about that: The value of `j++` is definitely used. It is used in the assignment to `j`.

Comment: The _point_ is that you should be doing `j++`, not `j = j++`.